# Can I sort list of Enum as I sort the list of string?

Tags: c#, sorting, enums, switch-statement

If I have a list of Enum for example

```
public enum Color
{
   Red,
   Blue,
   Yellow,
   Green,
   Black
}
```

And I have a list `List<Color> testList;`

For example, in my testList, I have Red, Yellow and Black

Can I sort my testList and hence I get Black, Red and Yellow as I use sort() for a list of string?

And if I would like to use a switch statement, is there any performance consideration I switch a string or an enum? Which one is faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can order them like this:

```
public enum Color { Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Black }

Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color))
    .OfType<Color>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.ToString());
```

Result:

[image: enum sorting]

Note: I purposely left out any detail regarding performance issues.. there won't be any noticeable performance issues in your `switch`.. so don't worry about it :)

Comment: Thanks! The last Answer I found related to this was using a Cast<T> instead of OfType<T>, and that was still sorting them by the numeric value of the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the value/s of you List through this.

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>(); testList.Sort();
```

As for using switch-case statement between enum and string, that I'm not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

As for sorting a list of enum values, using the default sort will only sort according to the order of the values in the enum.  Therefore in your example, the order won't change because they are in the same order in the enum.  To get an alphabetical sorting you need a custom sorter.  Something like this:

```
    int enumsort(Color a, Color b)
    {
        return a.ToString().CompareTo(b.ToString());
    }
```

Then sort your list like this:

```
testlist.Sort(enumsort);
```

You could also go the LINQ route and use the OrderBy method.  It might look like this:

```
testlist = testlist.OrderBy(x => x.ToString()).ToList<Color>();
```